# Spring Security 3.1.0 - Remember-me does not work as expected

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I am having a problem with Spring Security's 3.1.0 remember-me cookies. I need to find a solution ASAP and I cannot find the cause of this problem.

These are the steps I am following:

- Go to my app URL (e.g. http://myapp/app.htm)
- I am redirected to login page, so I log in
- Once logged in, close browser without logging out
- Open browser and go to my app URL

At this point I expect to enter my app bypassing the login form since the remember-me cookie is still in my browser. Despite that fact, **the login page appears again**.

- Go to my app URL again

Trying again, I can enter my app normally bypassing the login form.

This is quite confusing, and I cannot find an explanation so far.

I tried to debug both attempts and I found the following when Spring Security's RememberMeAuthenticationFilter was fired:

Attempt 1
request path = /app.htm: request.getCookies() did not contain my SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE, therefore I was redirected to login page
request path = /security/login.htm: at this point request.getCookies() DID have my SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE, and it was accepted; anyway, I had already been redirected to the login page

Attempt 2
The remember-me cookie had already been accepted, so I could enter my app without problem.

Below are the Spring Security XML configuration and the logs of both attempts.

Any help on this will be very much appreciated!

---

Spring Security configuration (I will omit everything about daoAuthenticationProvider and event listeners):

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:custom-filter ref="sessionLocaleResolvingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/security/*.htm" requires-channel="https" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/retrieve-password/*.htm" requires-channel="https" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/messagebroker/*" access="authenticated" requires-channel="http" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/platform/*.htm"
        access="hasRole('limited') or (authenticated and !hasRole('role1') and !hasRole('role2'))"
        requires-channel="http" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app.htm" access="authenticated" requires-channel="http" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="http" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/security/login.htm" default-target-url="/app.htm"
        login-processing-url="/security/process-login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/security/login.htm?error=true" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/security/logout.htm" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
        logout-success-url="/security/logout-success.htm" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <sec:anonymous/>
    <sec:remember-me use-secure-cookie="true" key="myAppServices" 
        services-ref="ipTokenBasedRememberMeServicesBean" />
    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied-access.htm"/>
</sec:http>

<bean id="sessionLocaleResolvingFilter" class="com.myapp.spring.security.SessionLocaleResolvingFilter" />
<bean class="com.myapp.spring.security.IPTokenBasedRememberMeServices"
    id="ipTokenBasedRememberMeServicesBean">
    <constructor-arg value="myAppServices"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myAppJdbcDaoImpl"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myAppPasswordEncoder" class="com.myapp.spring.security.MyAppPasswordEncoder" />
<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Other beans... -->
```

Log for the first attempt (replaced org.springframework with o.s and org.springframework.security with o.s.s):

```
o.s.s.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter:134 - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /app.htm?lang=en; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL]
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:127 - No HttpSession currently exists
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:85 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /app.htm?lang=en at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'o.s.s.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90550640: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /app.htm?lang=en at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /app.htm?lang=en at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/app.htm'; against '/messagebroker/*'
o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher:103 - Checking match of request : '/app.htm'; against '/app.htm'
o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:193 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app.htm?lang=en; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:298 - Previously Authenticated: o.s.s.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90550640: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: o.s.s.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1ce3388, returned: -1
o.s.s.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
o.s.s.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at o.s.s.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:205)
    at o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:114)
    at o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at o.s.s.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    (X more)

o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to 'http://arbad67464/services/security/login.htm'
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:269 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
o.s.s.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

o.s.s.web.access.channel.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint:55 - Redirecting to: https://arbad67464/services/security/login.htm
o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy:36 - Redirecting to 'https://arbad67464/services/security/login.htm'

o.s.s.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter:134 - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /security/login.htm; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:139 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:85 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@16de87. A new one will be created.
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionLocaleResolvingFilter'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'

o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /security/login.htm at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
com.myapp.spring.security.IPTokenBasedRememberMeServices:103 - Remember-me cookie detected
com.myapp.spring.security.IPTokenBasedRememberMeServices:118 - Remember-me cookie accepted
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager:152 - Authentication attempt using o.s.s.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider
```

Log of my second attempt:

```
o.s.s.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter:134 - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /app.htm?lang=en; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL]
o.s.s.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:158 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'o.s.s.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@7db9504: Authentication: o.s.s.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@7db9504: Principal: com.myapp.spring.security.MyAppUserImpl@9716c62c: Username: somebody@mail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: limited,premium,special; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: limited, premium, special'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /app.htm?lang=en at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter:142 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'o.s.s.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@7db9504: Principal: com.myapp.spring.security.MyAppUserImpl@9716c62c: Username: somebody@mail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: limited,premium,special; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: limited, premium, special'
o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy:318 - /app.htm?lang=en at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:107 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'o.s.s.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@7db9504: Principal: com.myapp.spring.security.MyAppUserImpl@9716c62c: Username: somebody@mail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: limited,premium,special; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: limited, premium, special'
o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:193 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app.htm?lang=en; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:298 - Previously Authenticated: o.s.s.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@7db9504: Principal: com.myapp.spring.security.MyAppUserImpl@9716c62c: Username: somebody@mail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: limited,premium,special; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: o.s.s.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@7798: RemoteIpAddress: fe80:0:0:0:ec09:25fb:3df4:323b; SessionId: 057E689401E69589BB7359F3E95B4A18; Granted Authorities: limited, premium, special
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: o.s.s.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1ce3388, returned: 1
o.s.s.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor:214 - Authorization successful
```

Comment: Please trim this down into something more easily digestible.  Right now, it's just a wall-of-text/code which makes it very easy for people to not take the time to look at it.  Additionally, just dumping all of your code and logs is an indicator of minimal effort in trying to find out the *actual* issue you have, and asking for assistance with *that* here.

Comment: Ok, I understand that it may be kind of overwhelming, so I will try to trim it down. But please understand that when I dumped my logs I only intended to provide additional information that may be useful for anyone wishing to help. It is not by itself an indicator of minimal effort - I read the logs carefully and debugged my app and tried to find a solution in several places before posting this. Additionally, I did not dump ALL of my code, only the XML. If I didn't, how could anyone possibly help?
Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

In the Spring security they provide 2 ways to use the rememberMe service.

1. In the rememberMeService Definition, set a property alwaysRememberMe is true.
   In this case whenever first time user try to access the secure URL it will take to login 
   page. once user logged in with correct user name and password, after onwards it wil not
   ask you for login until you logout.
2. In the login page add a remember me checkbox with name "_spring_security_remember_me"
   and value="true".
   In this case when user select the remember me check box then only it will able to access to
   secure URL without login page until u logout.

Its working for me..

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess it has something to do with the fact that you have some URLs configured to use HTTPS.

The remember-me cookie will have been marked as secure (you should be able to see this in the `set-cookie` header which your browser receives and probably also in the browser cookie cache). Since the request to `/app` is over HTTP, the cookie will not be sent. However, the request to the login page is redirected to HTTPS at which point the cookie *will* be sent.

You should really use HTTPS throughout. It is simpler to configure and your app isn't really secure otherwise. However, there is also a `use-secure-cookie` option in the [remember-me namespace element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-remember-me), which you can set to false to override the default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I tried erasing all the `requires-channel` attributes from my `<intercept-url>` elements in order not to force HTTPS in any case, and the remember-me cookie was detected in the first attempt.
I was asked to configure HTTPS the way I did in the XML despite the fact it is not completely secure, but maybe I will need to use it through the whole session so that these cookies work properly.

I will try to adjust the channel configuration. Once I am done with that, I will post the results.

Thanks a lot Luke!

Comment: Cool. Note that, as I said, you can also force the cookie to be marked as insecure so that it is sent over both HTTP and HTTPS if that's really what you want.